# Shrine + Dropzone with Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, coffeescript, dropzone.js

Im having trouble getting dropzone to upload to S3 with shrine.  When I attempt to upload an image I get the following error back from Amazon S3:

```
Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
```

Here is my Dropzone coffeescript code which handles the upload:

```
Dropzone.options.recipeImageDropzone = 
    init: ->
        myDropzone = this
        @on 'addedfile', (file) ->
            console.log(file)
            options =
                extension: file.name.match(/(\.\w+)?$/)[0]
                _: Date.now()
            $.getJSON '/images/cache/presign', options, (result) ->
                file.additionalData = result['fields']
                myDropzone.options.url = result['url']
                myDropzone.processQueue()
                return
            return
        @on 'sending', (file, xhr, formData) ->
            console.log(file.additionalData)
            console.log(file)
            formData['key'] = file.additionalData['key']
            formData['acl'] = file.additionalData['acl']
            formData['policy'] = file.additionalData['policy']
            formData['x-amz-credential'] = file.additionalData['x-amz-credential']
            formData['x-amz-algorithm'] = file.additionalData['x-amz-algorithm']
            formData['x-amz-date'] = file.additionalData['x-amz-date']
            formData['x-amz-signature'] = file.additionalData['x-amz-signature']
            console.log(formData)
            return
        @on 'success', (file) ->
            image = 
                id: file.formData.key.match(/cache\/(.+)/)[1]
                storage: 'cache'
                metadata:
                    size: file.size
                    filename: file.name.match(/[^\/\\]+$/)
                    mime_type: file.type
            $('#image-data__field').val(JSON.stringify(image))
        return
    paramName: 'file'
    maxFiles: 1
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*'
    autoProcessQueue: false
```

The getJSON returns the presign info from shrine for uploading the image to my cache folder.  The JSON stringified version of the fields info looks like this:

```
"key":"cache/cafb6e0ec68739e4b66a4d73af8df8da.jpg",
    "acl":"public-read", 
 "policy":"eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNi0xMi0yNVQxNzozMDozMFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJsaXZpbmctcmVjaXBlLWFzc2V0cyJ9LHsia2V5IjoiY2FjaGUvY2FmYjZlMGVjNjg3MzllNGI2NmE0ZDczYWY4ZGY4ZGEuanBnIn0seyJhY2wiOiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LHsieC1hbXotY3JlZGVudGlhbCI6IkFLSUFKU1JQR0s0TU5NMjVVWDJRLzIwMTYxMjI1L3VzLXdlc3QtMi9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QifSx7IngtYW16LWFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSx7IngtYW16LWRhdGUiOiIyMDE2MTIyNVQxNjMwMzBaIn1dfQ==",
    "x-amz-credential":"AKIA***********UX2Q/20161225/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request",
    "x-amz-algorithm":"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
    "x-amz-date":"20161225T163030Z",
    "x-amz-signature":"39d1818894564****************99f374c22304c8ec583aa5719529"},
    "url":"https://living-recipe-assets.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "processing":true
```

With this I get a 403 error with the message at the top.  Any help would be apprciated cause I am stumped and cant figure out how to fix this

**EDIT**

Here are the form (also updated my dropzone configuration a little cause had a old version pasted)

```
<form action="/images"
      class="dropzone"
      id="recipe-image-dropzone"></form>
```

And the output from the logs

file.additionalData (remove some of the key data):

```
Object
acl: "public-read"
key: "cache/32f48c42206046ed700c48d0509344f8.jpg"
policy: "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNi0xMi0yNlQxODoyODo1NFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJsaXZpbmctcmVjaXBlLWFzc2V0cyJ9LHsia2V5IjoiY2FjaGUvMzJmNDhjNDIyMDYwNDZlZDcwMGM0OGQwNTA5MzQ0ZjguanBnIn0seyJhY2wiOiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LHsieC1hbXotY3JlZGVudGlhbCI6IkFLSUFKU1JQR0s0TU5NMjVVWDJRLzIwMTYxMjI2L3VzLXdlc3QtMi9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QifSx7IngtYW16LWFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSx7IngtYW16LWRhdGUiOiIyMDE2MTIyNlQxNzI4NTRaIn1dfQ=="
x-amz-algorithm: "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
x-amz-credential: "AKI******K4MNM25UX2Q/20161226/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request"
x-amz-date: "20161226T172854Z"
x-amz-signature: "f5fabb30edb********7f96bf141f33e9752932977a9c0813b47c9695727"
```

**EDIT 2**
After putting the console.log after the loop it was still blank, so as a test I manually assigned each field (since its only 7) and that seemed to work in setting the formData as the console log (see modified code above) outputs this now:

```
FormData
acl: "public-read"
key: "cache/7bb7f3213ef12c688b2edca9c01f58a2.jpg"
policy: "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNi0xMi0yNlQxODo1MToyOVoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJsaXZpbmctcmVjaXBlLWFzc2V0cyJ9LHsia2V5IjoiY2FjaGUvN2JiN2YzMjEzZWYxMmM2ODhiMmVkY2E5YzAxZjU4YTIuanBnIn0seyJhY2wiOiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LHsieC1hbXotY3JlZGVudGlhbCI6IkFLSUFKU1JQR0s0TU5NMjVVWDJRLzIwMTYxMjI2L3VzLXdlc3QtMi9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QifSx7IngtYW16LWFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSx7IngtYW16LWRhdGUiOiIyMDE2MTIyNlQxNzUxMjlaIn1dfQ=="
x-amz-algorithm: "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
x-amz-credential: "AKIAJSRPGK4MNM25UX2Q/20161226/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request"
x-amz-date: "20161226T175129Z"
x-amz-signature: "e5f22b70f27062da02f1556fc08256a7881de615735e4f57c68bb1c43ceb4788"
```

However, now Im getting this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Error>
  <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
  <Message>Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'. If it is specified, please check the order of the fields.</Message>
  <ArgumentName>key</ArgumentName>
  <ArgumentValue></ArgumentValue>
  <RequestId>33B941097CBBC2DE</RequestId>
  <HostId>U+s9AKZ1YL3AXqAUtUjzpjIE/ffe9ZZAbrOE7ZRr0F04/0HAN3kS7JbEOcZ8/T8WWjQ0lYPyFIY=</HostId>
 </Error>
```

Looking at the network traffic when Im attempt an upload the payload doesnt seem to include the formData, here is the headers:

```
Request URL:https://living-recipe-assets.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Remote Address:52.218.160.85:443
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:PUT, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:5000
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/xml
Date:Mon, 26 Dec 2016 18:01:36 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2:69vX+IYrmSPh8Iwlj2QudR7UWogWzjZhUhBKPEZZwJuLJ0onlo6V4w3j2JwZH+ZCuJUsHr7Iji8=
x-amz-request-id:830FB182B5A005B2
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:204526
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryA39A0ZENXfuLbEem
Host:living-recipe-assets.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/recipes/new
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryA39A0ZENXfuLbEem

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="20161013-tuttorosso-jambalaya-vicky-wasik-3.jpg"

Content-Type: image/jpeg





------WebKitFormBoundaryA39A0ZENXfuLbEem--
```

Comment: Can you post your form code....and also the output of `console.log(file.additionalData)` and `console.log(formData)` on your `sending` call?

Comment: See changes made to question, after some playing around and cleaning up my code (lots of trial and error lead to some missing of cleaning up) the error seems to be with the formData not being changed to match the additionalData

Comment: Nice....you need to place this line `console.log(formData)` before the `return` in order to check the data.

Comment: Worked that and did some changes and have gotten some progress but still getting an error, see edits, and thanks for the helps

Comment: @DRing did you figure this out? I'm using your coffeescript code in my own app since I couldn't find any other examples for Shrine + Dropzone. But now I'm running into this error too :)

Comment: @DRing I found your solution in the Google Groups post, here it is for anyone else who comes across this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ruby-shrine/JZPYbR1NwLs/LuBAKcFjDwAJ